# how to exclude a widget from setState?

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, setstate, scaffold

I am designing an application that uses setState to refresh a screen with all its widgets, however I would like to know if there is a way to exclude a particular widget (conainer) and all its children, as if I were treating it as a new page.

I tried to use Navigator.push (context, MaterialPageRoute), but it didn't work, I would like to treat the widget as a separate page. I appreciate any help

Comment: Can you include sample code that will reproduce the same issue. More about [asking good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You can change where the `setState` is called, create a separate `StatefulWidget` that contains only the ones that need to be rebuilded. However in most of the cases this is not possible because of the order you need to show your widgets or many other factors. That's when State Managements tools come in handy. You should try to learn how to use `Provider`, `Riverpod` or `BLoC` (which i personally recommend). If you want something a litte bit easier you can start learning how to use `InheritedWidget` starting in the documentation [right here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html).

Comment: I can't change where I call setstate, because I do that in a main widget, for example, I have this tree of widgets

main
main/widget1
main/widget2 

main/widget2/wiget21/widget211
main/widget2/widget22

I hope the example is clear.
my setstate is in widget2, since it is in charge of doing other processes in real time, and the widget that I want to exclude is widget 211, an alternative solution that you mention is using state managers, I did it with Getx and it seems to work . thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

use `const` if possible. if not,

use [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) , if you call setState inside this widget, the outside widget is not touched. Maybe it will suit what you need